# Create UIButton same style of UISearchBar cancel button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, uisearchbar

I want to make UIButton.
It has same style of "UISearchBar cancel button".
I want to know style setting code of "UISearchBar cancel button".

Please teach me.

```
cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,30)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to create a round button with a X inside it.

You can't simply set a style on the button to achieve this.
You should create a button and set your custom image.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"];
[cancelbutton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Take a look at the documentation: [UIButton Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

Comment: Hi
Thank you for your reply.
I consider UINavigationButton too.but there is no guarantee.